# How to get request body in angular from ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular5

As i can get the query params by using ActivatedRoute which is get request. but how can i get request body by using ActivatedRoute from post request. If ActivatedRoute is not right option to get then how should i get request body

This is my jsp code:-

```
    var res = "url which i am creating";
                var url =res[0];
                var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
                mapForm.target = "Test";
                mapForm.method = "post";
                mapForm.action = url;



              //Splitting parameters from url to add into body
              var res1 =res[1].split("=");
              var name = res1[0];
              var value = res1[1];
                mapInput3 = document.createElement("input");
                mapInput3.type = "hidden";
                mapInput3.name =name;
                mapInput3.value = value;
                mapForm.appendChild(mapInput3);

                document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

                map = window.open("", "Test", "menubar,   
                      toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, 
                      resizable, dependent, width=1200, height=600, 
             left=0,top=0");

            if (map) {
                mapForm.submit();
           }

this is my angular code:-
 this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.authKey = params['auth_key'];
    });
```

Now if I sent parameter through get method from jsp, I am able to get it from above angular code.

but if i sent params through post method then i get message as " Cannot post"

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to get the body of the query.
You can use snapshot.get and when declare a it with a value something like this ->
const t = this.route.snapshot.mapedQuery.get()

The value of- t is your query body.

Answered from my phone so I can’t format the code

Comment: Nope, not the body of the query, As i am sending some parameters in post method through request body but as I hit the angular url  "Cannot POST /" this message comes. Does it mean that we can not send post request or am I doing something wrong while sending request

Comment: Can you please add code to your question it’s kinder hard to understand what you want to do

Comment: Can you please take a look i have updated the question with code?

Comment: @vikrantbute have you tried using postman? its free tool to check if you API even sends the correct info very easy to use. i am no JSP master but just from looking at your error its seems that your method of using POST is incorrect. and what are you subscribing to in your angular? in order to subscribe to a service in angular you need to first make a service class and then subscribe to it in your component i can show you how in the answer if you want.

Comment: I have tried with postman but no luck, got same message as "Cannot POST /" and ActivatedRoute is an inbuilt class provided by angular so i think there is no need to create service class.

Comment: When you send a request to your service you need to subscribe to it. You can’t subscribe to the ActivatedRpute to get your data/post with it. If the postman didn’t work there is problem with the API. That you created